# If a man gave 'mishloach manot' on Purim to a woman, did he fulfull the mitzvah?

Tags: halacha, women, mistakes, men-male, mishloach-manot

In the Shulchan Aruch 695, the Rema states that a man should not send manot to a woman to avoid the problem of safek kiddushin. If he did send the gift to a woman (and suppose that was the only gift he sent) did he fulfill the mitzvah?

Comment: Why would you think he hasn't?

Comment: I believe that SA advises not to do it this way, but, it doesn't seem to indicate that if you did this, you get no mitzvah points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the mitzva was absolutely fulfilled. It's practical advice not to do so (between *single people*), but nowhere near a sufficiently strong thou-shalt-not as to constitute a mitzva-fulfilled-through-a-sin.